# C# Create a Rectangle class that holds width and height.

Tags: c#, html, css

This is for C#
Create a Rectangle class that holds width and height. Provide a constructor that accepts width and height. The Rectangle class contains three methods, to calculate the perimeter, to calculate the area, and to check whether it is square or not respectively.

### So far I got this done..

```
    public double width;
    public double height;

    public Rectangle(double w, double h)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public double perimeter()
    {
        return 2 * (width + height);
    }
    public double area()
    {
        return width * height;
    }
    public boolean isSquare()
    {
        if (width == height)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

}

I get an error for this line

```
        }
    public boolean isSquare()
    {
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Coming to C# from Java, perhaps? In C#, it's `bool`, not `boolean`.

Comment: `if (width == height){return true;}else{return false;}` can be reduced to `return width==height;`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `bool` instead of `boolean`. Try this code:

```
  public bool isSquare()
    {
        if (width == height)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!